# Update shape position with Canvas and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, canvas, socket.io

Using NodeJS and Socket.io, I'm making a quick canvas app that moves a shape across the screen. This data will appear on all clients. Each square is timestamped to determine draw order.
Below is client.html. It says that I "cannot set property lastUpdate" of undefined. How is it considered undefined? I tried defining it so many times at the top. What's wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    "use strict";

    var canvas;
    var ctx;
    var socket;

    //var lastUpdate = new Date().getTime();

    /*var square = {
        lastUpdate: new Date().getTime(),
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        height: 100,
        width: 100
    };*/

    //
    //var person = {name: 'user' + (Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000)) + 1)};
    //var user = 'user' + (Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000)) + 1);
    //var user = Object.keys(something about name);
    //var user = Object.keys(user);
    //function person(name) {
      //this.name = name;
    //}
    //var user = Object.keys(person);

   //lets try using a prototype
   /*function user(lastUpdate, x, y, width, height)  {
     this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
     this.width = width;
     this.height = height;
   }*/

  var name = {lastUpdate: new Date().getTime(), x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100};

   var user = Object.keys(name);


    var draws = {};


    function updatePosition() {
        var message = {
            xUpdate: 10,
            yUpdate: 5
        }
        socket.emit('movementUpdate', message);
    }

    /*function redraw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        ctx.fillRect(square.x, square.y, square.width, square.height);
    }*/

    //
    function draw() {

     ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

     var keys = Object.keys(draws);

     for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
    {
       var drawCall = draws[keys[i]];

      //order to draw
      //gets drawcalls instead of var square
      ctx.fillRect(drawCall.x, drawCall.y, drawCall.width, drawCall.height);
    }

  }

  //
  function setup() {

     var time = new Date().getTime();
     //console.log(time);
     var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(300-10) + 10); //random x position
     var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*(300-10) + 10); //random y position
     draws[user] = {lastUpdate: time, x: x, y: y, width: 100, height: 100};

  }

    /*function update(data) {
        square = data;
        redraw();
    }*/

    //
    function handleMessage(data) {

       if(!draws[data.name])
       {
         draws[data.name] = data.coords;
       }
       else if(data.coords.lastUpdate > draws[data.name].lastUpdate)
       {
         draws[data.name] = data.coords;
       }

       draw(); //redraw after updates

    }


    function init() {
        canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        socket = io.connect();
        socket.on('connect', function () {
            //setInterval(updatePosition, 1000);
            setInterval(function()
          {

              var time = new Date().getTime();
              //console.log(time);
              console.log(draws);

              **draws[user].lastUpdate = time; //lastUpdate is UNDEFINED**
              draws[user].x += 5;

              socket.emit('draw', {name: user, coords: draws[user]});

              draw();

          }, 3000);

        });

        socket.on('updatedDraw', handleMessage);
        //socket.on('updatedMovement', updatePosition); //UNDEFINED, used to be 'update'. Could it be 'handleMessage'?
    }

  window.onload = init;
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" height="500" width="500">Please use an HTML 5     browser</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the line that gets the error: **draws[user].lastUpdate = time; //lastUpdate is UNDEFINED**

Comment: From what I can see, you don't add anything to `draws` variable. How could it contain your `user`? You've added `console.log(draws);` before that line, what does it show? What is the purpose of using those Object.keys(...)? And it seems that you can't name you variable `name` cause it refers to `window.name`. Your code seems to be very chaotic.